# AngularJs how to use $scope in callback method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I'm new to `AngularJs` and have some issues with the `controller`

For me this is working great:

```
var m= angular.module('m', []);

m.controller('myC', function myC($scope) {
    $scope.myVal  = [{/*..*/}]; //assigning values directly
});
```

used e.g. like this

```
<div data-ng-app="m">
    <div ng-controller="myC">
        {{myVal}}
    </div>
<div>
```

but I have a bit more complex method to acquire the data I want to use in `myVal`. Therfore I try to transfer the `$scope` to use it in an callback method (a web request is performed there, which take some time, but values get returned!). My approach is the following:

```
var m= angular.module('m', []);

var s;
m.controller('myC', function myC($scope) {
    s = $scope;
    bigFunction("foo1", "foo2", myCallback);
});

function myCallback(a, b) {
    s.myVal = b; //trying to assign the value to $scope
}
```

but Angular is not working anymore. The same (as above listed) html snippit is not working anymore. But `myCallback` is called!

Have I missed something obviously? Or: How can I access `$scope` in the callback method in order to use it in the Angular within an HTML page?

Comment: Why do you need to have `myCallback` outside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.bind` to set the value of `this` inside `myCallback` to `$scope`:

```
m.controller('myC', function myC($scope) {
    bigFunction("foo1", "foo2", myCallback.bind($scope));
});

function myCallback(a, b) {
    this.myVal = b; //trying to assign the value to $scope
}
```

Or, you could use `.bind` to set the first parameter:

```
m.controller('myC', function myC($scope) {
    bigFunction("foo1", "foo2", myCallback.bind(null, $scope));
});

function myCallback($scope, a, b) {
    $scope.myVal = b; //trying to assign the value to $scope
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but for some reason its not working for me. myVal will not appear in the html file. Are there any limits on the time that `bigFunction` is allowed to use?